# Are there differences in the linkers between VS2017 and VS2015?

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2017

For many years I have been using a library 'wot I wrote' which has a particular peculiarity in that it defines `main()`.

This means that applications that I write don't have to have `main` themselves because the linker already has an unresolved reference to it and goes looking for it and finds it in my library.

This technique has worked on several platforms including VS2005/2008/2015. Now I have just installed VS2017 and started a new project referencing the library which was built with VS2015.

The new project only has one source file like this:

```
// necessary #includes elided
namespace gp {
    void Options(Run& runner) {
        runner << "test2017";
    }
}
```

My expectation is that this file will compile and link with my library (for instance the type `Run` is declared and defined there).

The linker then complains:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

However, simply adding these lines to the one source file:

```
int main(int, char*[]);
auto p = &main;
```

the program links and runs and I get the expected output:

```
**** test2017 ****
```

Comment: Why is your main extern „C“?

Comment: Ok, good spot. The `extern "C"` is irrelevant. I'll remove it from the question. I put it in at some point whilst trying to get the linker to work, but never removed it to check. Thanks.

Comment: Does it change anything if you recompile the library with 2017?

Comment: Maybe it is searching for `WinMain` instead of `main`? What happens if you specify `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to the linker?

Comment: @MarcGlisse That's my next step. But I can't do it just now.....

Comment: @geza: Ok, That's it! Please write this up as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to the linker. It's because maybe it searches for `WinMain` instead of `main`.

In the Property Pages of your project you can set this in Linker/System/SubSystem and select `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` (instead of `Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)`)

Comment: The root cause was because I created a new Empty Project. I think I should have created a new Windows Console Application.